# The element implicitly contains an 'any' type because no index signature is assigned to the type '{}'

Tags: typescript

I have this typescript code, for an Express application:

```
for (var propertyName in req.body) {
    console.log(req.body[propertyName]);
}
```

that work correctly

Now i reuse in another typescript application, but i got this error:

[ts] L'elemento contiene implicitamente un tipo 'any' perché al tipo '{}' non è assegnata alcuna firma dell'indice.

[ts] The element implicitly contains an 'any' type because no index signature is assigned to the type '{}'.

I don't understand the error

The error is in

```
req.body[propertyName]
```

How can I assign the signature to the index?

Comment: Can we see the code where you use this again and get the error?

Comment: Could you please post a complete example. This code works for me (with `strict`): `import * as express from "express";
export class Index {
    public index(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
        for (var propertyName in req.body) {
            console.log(req.body[propertyName]);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: What typings are installed or which type is interpreted for the body field of the request parameter? The type of `body` is of type `any` in the `Request` interface from the Express namespace.

Comment: Download this project: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter   Then add the 3 lines of code I posted in server.ts

I do not understand why typescript is so boring:
the syntax changes from one project to another

Answer (score 6):

> How can I assign the signature to the index?

The type `req` is not under your control.

## Fix

Use `any`:

```
console.log((req as any).body[propertyName]);
```

And now if your JS worked, your TS will too

## More

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/migrating.html
- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Comment: Yesterday I lost 4 hours for this stupid mistake
Thank you